# Why accessing database via lua script deletes -wal file?

Tags: android, sqlite, lua, wal

I have a question concerning SQLite & Lua. Basically i'm trying to use SQLite in WAL mode in my Android app. However if i perform a particular set of operations with database from my Lua script, it deletes `-wal` file. It leads to the problem: some of my transactions could be lost if the device loses power, and i don't have opportunity to close DB connection properly. The flow is attached in picture below.
[image: The process flow]

Database opened this way (c++):
`int32 rcOpen = sqlite3_open(filename.c_str(), &handle);`

Also, after connection opened, i use this `pragma`'s

```
PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL;
PRAGMA synchronous=FULL;
```

- Also tried `PRAGMA synchronous=EXTRA + PRAGMA locking_mode=EXCLUSIVE` - didn't make any difference
- Also tried using file controle mode `SQLITE_FCNTL_PERSIST_WAL` - didn't make any difference either

```
int enabled = 1;
int rcControl = sqlite3_file_control(handle, "main", SQLITE_FCNTL_PERSIST_WAL, &enabled);
```

Stack: android 7 (fs ext4) - JNI (NDK 21.4.7075529) - c++ 11 - sqlite 3.27.2 - lua 5.3.4

The lua script i use for reproducing the problem:

```
function prequire(name)
    local status, lib = pcall(require, name)
    if(status) then return lib end
    --Library failed to load
    return nil
end

print("start lua")

local sqlite3 = prequire("lsqlite3complete")
if sqlite3 == nil then
    print('No lsqlite3')
    return
end

local db = sqlite3.open('/data/data/ru.chromesearcher.sqlitewal/files/database.sqlite3')
if db == nil then
    print("db open failed")
    return
end


print("query start")

local stmt = db:prepare('SELECT * FROM paymentevents where pe_amount=?')
local amount = 3000
stmt:bind_values(amount)
stmt:finalize()

db:close()
```

Comment: That's normal. Once the WAL has been applied to the main database, there's no reason to have it anymore, until the next alteration.

Comment: But why i lose transactions after all? If WAL applied to the main database, all transactions should remain after closing app and re-opening it. I see direct connection between deleting WAL file and losing data. Even if i do a checkpoint (which is literally moving data from WAL to main DB) - WAL file is not deleted and data is not lost

Comment: Do you commit the transactions? Terminating the application while it has open transactions will cause any data in the uncommitted transaction to be lost.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo yep, i do manually commit transactions by `BEGIN TRANSACTION;` + `END TRANSACTION;`. I check if transactions have been commited via registered sqlite_wal_hook, which shows that number of pages in WAL file increases. However i am not sure what happens to transactions that are transferred from WAL file to main DB file during checkpoint.